# How to remove text between two strings in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

Hello i want to remove the text between 2 strings example:

Input:

[0:10:56] BizzyBoo [0:10:56] Fixx [0:10:56] EvilSanta [0:10:56] Romeo

and i need output like this:

BizzyBoo|Fixx|EvilSanta|Romeo     etc..

without gaps just like that all in one line. Can i make it in notepad ++? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to write yourself some regex for that. Also Santa is not evil.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do in the notepad++.

Add your text in the notepad++ and Open Find Replace box in the notepad++ by using CTRL + H Shortcut key and in the FIND box add blank space using SPACE Key and Click on replace all button.